# Max Heap & Min Heap Initializations (Java) Priority Queue

Tags: java

What is the difference between :

```
  PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
  PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

And

```
  PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
  PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a - b);
```

I did some leetcode questions and it seems like the first one passes more test cases than the one below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `compare` function, `a - b` and `b - a` don't give correct results when `a` and `b` are too far apart.  It's because because of a little thing called **overflow**.

Consider `a - b`, the supposed "natural order" comparator function for integers. It *looks* like it should work, right?  Let's try some examples:

1. Let `a==2` and `b==5`.  A natural-order comparator should return a negative number, to indicate that `a < b`.  `a - b` -> `2 - 5` -> `-3`.  QED.
2. Let `a==345` and `b==-197`; `a > b`, so we want a positive result from the comparator.  `a - b` -> `245 - (-197)` -> `245 + 197` -> `442`.  QED.
3. Let `a==100` and `b==100`.  The comparator should return zero to indicate `a == b`.  `a - b` -> `100 - 100` -> 0.  QED.

So far, so good, yes?

Now try this: Let `a==Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2_147_483_648) and `b==1`. Quite obiously, `a < b`, so the comparator should return a negative number.  `a - b` -> `-2_147_483_648 - 1` -> `-2_147_483_649`. QED, right?

**WRONG!** The result is actually **positive** 2_147_483_647!  Why?  **Overflow**, that's why.  An `int` can hold 32 bits, and the actual answer of -2_147_483_649 requires 33 bits to represent it. The extra bit of the actual answer gets thrown away and the 32 bits we're left with represent the value 2_147_483_647.  So our compare function returns a positive result and thus erroneously indicates that `a > b`.